# R, Java, and SOAP Webservices

Tags: java, r, web-services, soap, wsdl

How can I expose an R function through Java using SOAP web service? I have tried that invoking R function from Java using R-Serve and it is working fine. But I am unable to create WSDL from Java code which is calling R function using R-script.I am facing this error and below is my Java code. I am creating WSDL using Eclipse plugin.

```
Jun 24, 2016 5:11:39 PM org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletlogException
INFO: Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rosuda/REngine/Rserve/RserveException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.cache.ClassCache.lookup(ClassCache.java:85)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:428)



package com.analytics;

import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;
```

This is my Java code which is used to generate WSDL using Eclipse plugin.
    public class Temp implements Add {

```
    @Override
    public int add(int x, int y) {
         RConnection connection = null;
         int sum = 0;

            try {
                /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
                 * 6311
                 */
                connection = new RConnection();

                /* Note four slashes (\\\\) in the path */
                connection.eval("source('D:\\\\MyScript.R')");     //attaching R script         
                sum=connection.parseAndEval("myadd("+x+","+y+")").asInteger();  // call to R function

            } catch (RserveException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (REngineException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Here is my R code which is being called from above given Java code
MyScript.R

```
Myadd<-function (x, y) {
  sum=x+y
  return (sum)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to include Rserve.jar and Rengine.jar in libs folder. The missing classes are present in the jar. The jars are available in R package at path \library\Rserve\client\java.